# tensorflow slice with negative size

Tags: tensorflow

In this tutorial
    http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson4/
Its calling the tensorflow slice method on some image data
    raw_image_data = mpimg.imread(filename)

```
image = tf.placeholder("uint8", [None, None, 3])
slice = tf.slice(image, [1000, 0, 0], [3000, -1, -1])
```

from the slice definition
    tf.slice(input_, begin, size, name=None)

I take it means start with pixel 1000,0 R layer (out of rgb), take a slice of size 3000, -1, and minus layer by -1. I am lost on how you can go -1 from 0 for both the second image dimension and the rgb layer.

Any knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 here is equivalent to "*" or "take all in that dimension", i.e. per [documentation](https://g3doc.corp.google.com/learning/brain/public/g3doc/python/functions_and_classes/shard6/tf.slice.md?cl=head) "if size[i] is -1, all remaining elements in dimension i are included in the slice."

In other words, if

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Then

```
tf.slice(x, [0, 0], [1, -1])
```

would return

```
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: may I ask why wouldn't it return [1 2], since only two dimensions are specified in the slice call.

Comment: [0, 0] means we begin slicing at row 0, column 0.  [1, -1] means for dimension 0 (the row), take 1 element, for dimension 1 (the column), takes all elements.

Comment: but the 3 in [1 2 3] is dimension 2, which is not mentioned in the slice call. So why would the result contain dimension 2?

Comment: The value '3' at in index [0, 2].  (Dimension 0's index 0, dimension 1's index 2).   There's no dimension 2.  It is included because the "-1" in the size argument [1, -1] means include all elements for dimension 1.  The "1" in size argument [1, -1] means include only 1 row (in the dimension 0 space).

Answer (score 3):

`-1` is a special value in tensor's size definitions.

It doesn't mean `-1` but it means **everything**.

At the line

```
image = tf.placeholder("uint8", [None, None, 3])
```

You're defining a placeholder with shape `(?, ?, 3)`.

In the following line:

```
slice = tf.slice(image, [1000, 0, 0], [3000, -1, -1])
```

Your're defining the `slice` operation. This operation means:

Extract a slice from `image` whose shape is`(?, ?, 3)`.

Starting from position `(1000, 0, 0)` extract a slice with shape `(3000, ?, 3)`.

The `3000` means that the returned slice will have `3000` elements, extracted from `image`, after position `1000` in dimension `0`.

The `?` means that Tensorflow will determine at run time the value (is not possibile due to `image` undefined shape).

`3` is inferred by `image`. Every element of the extract slice will have a depth of `3`.